# Reverse Engineering an ELF Binary

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering

I have a binary from a potential exploit that was found on a server. I am interested in reversing it to see exactly what this binary was designed to attempt to exploit. My only problem is OBJDump and other similar programs will all return errors indicating that the file cannot be read. Hex dump shows that an ELF header does exist in the file however I am not proficient enough to identify if the ELF is properly build based purely off the hex.

Comment: Try modifying the ELF headers to have sane values. A common anti-debugging trick is to put insane values in some fields, e.g: setting the size of program/section headers to some large value, so debugging tools try to allocate too much and fail. Of course, after that, there could be more anti-debugging tricks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [IDA](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml) (Interactive Disassembler). [Demo versions](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_demo.shtml) can open ELF files. (I'm not sure if [freeware](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml) can, and it's Windows only). We work hard on making it accept damaged/deliberately corrupted files, so if it can't be loaded by IDA but works in the actual OS, I'll be interested in a sample.

Disclaimer: I work for Hex-Rays.

Comment: Yeah that was going to be my next step in this process however I do not have access to IDA atm(no windows boxes). I was hoping for another solution such as some funky way of calling OBJDump or a cross platform solution.

Comment: Demo versions are available for Linux and OS X.

Comment: @Blackninja543 I'm using Hex-Rays disassembler flawlessly with Wine on a 32bit Ubuntu box.

Comment: Confirming the free version of IDA (currently 5.5) does open ELF binaries, as long as they are 32 bit.